# Android:Increasing and decreasing the int value of a textview with a button click

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have a method in my class named InvokeService() and inside It I am storing an Int value from a remoteservice.

like this

```
int hvactemp=remoteService.getHvacTemp();
```

and I am storing this value in to a textview.

```
drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(hvactemp));
```

Now I want to incresae and decrease this value on button click.

I have two buttons declared in my code and the problem is

If I click right button the value is Increasing

suppose the value is 30 its increasing like 30,31,32,33,34,35 and so on..

But the problem is when I click left button its not decresing from the value Which I have present, as I said after incresing the value is 35 so now If I press left button it should go like this 34,32,31,32

but its decreasing from 30,29,28,27 instead of 35,34,32,31

How to solve this?

Here is my code.

```
 private void invokeService() {

    if (conn == null) {
        // Toast.makeText(CarHome.this, "Cannot invoke - service not bound",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        try {
            System.out.println(remoteService);

            int rpm = remoteService.getEnginRPM();
            int temp = remoteService.getTemperature();
            // int battery = remoteService.getBatteryLevel();
            int speed = remoteService.getSpeed();
            final int hvactemp = remoteService.getHvacTemp();
            System.out.println("Raghav hvac" + hvactemp);

            System.out.println("jaydeep speed" + speed);
            // rpm_text.setText(rpm);


        drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(hvactemp));


            driverbtnright.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                int hvactemp=remoteService.getHvacTemp();



                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    hvactemp++;
                    drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(hvactemp));
                     System.out.println("Raghav hvac" + hvactemp);


                }
            });

            driverbtnleft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                int hvactemp=remoteService.getHvacTemp();
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    //  drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(hvactemp));
                    hvactemp --;
                    drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(hvactemp));
                     System.out.println("Raghav decrement hvac" + hvactemp);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong with code flow.

Remove this `int hvactemp=remoteService.getHvacTemp();` from two click Listener and declare `hvactemp` as a class variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
        driverbtnright.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               int increase = Integer.parseInt((String)driverbtnright.getText())+1;

               driverbtnright.setText(increase);


            }
        });

        driverbtnleft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int hvactemp=remoteService.getHvacTemp();
            public void onClick(View v) {

            int decrease= Integer.parseInt((String)driverbtnright.getText())-1;

               driverbtnright.setText(decrease);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String t = drivertmpcount.getText().toString();

    int a = Integer.parseInt(t);
    a--;

    drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(a));
                         System.out.println("Raghav decrement hvac" + a);
```

It's happening because you are referring to hvactemp instead of current text of edittext.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried  but its showing  type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int at this line  int a = drivertmpcount.getText().toString();

Comment: You can manage that by using Integer.parseInt (String s). I am updating code

Answer (score 1):

Declare hvactemp as global integer where it will gets set in default oncreate method and button clicks(increments and decrements) which will later be used to settext in textviews.

```
       private int hvactemp; //declare it globally
       hvactemp = remoteService.getHvacTemp(); 

    drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(hvactemp));


        driverbtnright.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                hvactemp++;
                drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(hvactemp));
                 System.out.println("Raghav hvac" + hvactemp);


            }
        });

        driverbtnleft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                hvactemp --;
                drivertmpcount.setText(Integer.toString(hvactemp));
                 System.out.println("Raghav decrement hvac" + hvactemp);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I try This...see my code..

```
plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);

    plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txt_number.setText(Integer.toString(textvalue));
            textvalue++;
        }
    });

    minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textvalue--;
            txt_number.setText(Integer.toString(textvalue));
        }
    });
```